# What is the best way to merge multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I currently have a data structure that looks something like:

```
agents = {
 'medic': {'medic1': {...}},
 'police': {'police1': {...}, 'police2': {...}},
}
```

Each key in the sub dictionaries is guaranteed to be unique. I want to create a new dictionary from these dictionaries (I'm marshalling data, before sending it to another program).

My current way is:

```
new_dict = {}
for d in agents.values():
    new_dict.update(d)
assert new_dict == {'medic1': {...}, 'police1': {...}, 'police2': {...}}
```

This is a bit verbose for something quite simple. There's also this one liner. But as with most one liners it begins to lack clarity.

```
from itertools import chain
new_dict = dict(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in agents.values()))
```

I also know that in python 3.5 I will be able to do something like:

```
new_dict = {**d for d in agents.values()}
```

Is there a smarter way to create this dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{k: v for d in agents.values() for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dict constructor:

```
A = {"Y":2,"X":4}
B = {"Z":1,"Q":5}

C = dict(A, **B);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have more dictionaries than in the example, so this wouldn't work. Good work around for just two dictionaries though.